# Почему падает приложение Android?

Tags: android

Не могу понять, в чем причина падения приложения?

Стектрейс:

```
03-24 01:25:00.701 2998-2998/com.navesilli.sergey.galleryapp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.navesilli.sergey.galleryapp, PID: 2998
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.navesilli.sergey.galleryapp/com.navesilli.sergey.galleryapp.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class android.support.v7.app.AlertController.RecycleListView
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2665)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726)
at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class android.support.v7.app.AlertController.RecycleListView
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class android.support.v7.app.AlertController.RecycleListView
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.support.v7.app.AlertController.RecycleListView" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.navesilli.sergey.galleryapp-2/base.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.navesilli.sergey.galleryapp-2/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.navesilli.sergey.galleryapp-2/split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.navesilli.sergey.galleryapp-2/split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.navesilli.sergey.galleryapp-2/split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.navesilli.sergey.galleryapp-2/split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.navesilli.sergey.galleryapp-2/split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.navesilli.sergey.galleryapp-2/split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.navesilli.sergey.galleryapp-2/split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.navesilli.sergey.galleryapp-2/split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.navesilli.sergey.galleryapp-2/split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.navesilli.sergey.galleryapp-2/split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.navesilli.sergey.galleryapp-2/lib/x86, /system/lib, /vendor/lib]]
at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:380)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:609)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:787)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:727)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:858)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:821)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:518)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:426)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:377)
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:287)
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139)
at com.navesilli.sergey.galleryapp.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:33)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6679)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2618)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726)
at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477)
```

**Activity_main.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

    <LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/activity_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".MainActivity"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        >

<include
    layout="@layout/toolbar_layout"></include>

<android.support.v7.app.AlertController.RecycleListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
    android:scrollbars="vertical">

    </android.support.v7.app.AlertController.RecycleListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

[image: скрин]

Comment: в библиотеке поддержки нет никакого класса `AlertController` ничего удивительного, что вы получаете ошибку при попытке провести его инфлейт. Каким образом у вас получился такой путь до виджета `RecyclerView` ?

Comment: Всё делал исключительно по данному туториалу - https://www.androidhive.info/2016/04/android-glide-image-library-building-image-gallery-app/

Comment: но там нет никаких упоминаний о `AlertController` вообще ..

Comment: Извиняюсь, по этому - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YBXRB3CP89Q Кстати, да, на 18.39 ошибся в выборе параметра.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В xml вместо `android.support.v7.app.AlertController.RecycleListView` напишите `android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >

    <include
        layout="@layout/toolbar_layout">
    </include>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:scrollbars="vertical">

    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

</LinearLayout>
```